# Why compiler gives undefined reference error

Tags: c++, c++14, leveldb

I have a header file defined as `db.hpp` as follows:

```cpp
#ifndef PMT_DB_H
#define PMT_DB_H

#include <leveldb/db.h>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

class DBConnection {
    private:
        std::string db_file_;
        leveldb:: DB* db_;
        leveldb::Status status_;
        std::map<std::string, std::string> uncommitted_;

    public:
        DBConnection(const std::string &db_file);
        // Other functions
};

#endif
```

My `db.cpp` class is as follows:

```cpp
#include "db.hpp"

#include <leveldb/write_batch.h>
#include <string>


DBConnection::DBConnection(const std::string &db_file) {
    db_file_ = db_file;

    leveldb::Options options;
    options.create_if_missing = true;

    status_ = leveldb::DB::Open(options, db_file, &db_);
}

 // other functions
```

Here is how my main file `patricia-merkle-trie.cpp` looks like:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "core/db.hpp"

void say_hello(){
    std::cout << "Hello, from patricia-merkle-trie!\n";
}

int main() {
    say_hello();

    const std::string db_path_ {"/tmp/testdb"};
    DBConnection db_connection = DBConnection(db_path_);
    // Rest of the code
}
```

I tried to compile this with the following command:

```sh
g++ patricia-merkle-trie.cpp -o pmt_test -pthread -L/usr/local/lib -lleveldb -std=c++14
```

It gives me error as follows:

```cpp
/tmp/ccH2lHTf.o: In function `main':
patricia-merkle-trie.cpp:(.text+0x87): undefined reference to `DBConnection::DBConnection(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I know this is a linker error, but not getting why this error is coming. I have defined the content string as a parameter to the constructor, the definition and declaration of the constructor are exactly the same. Then why does it show the call to the constructor as two parametrized?

Comment: You're not compiling `db.cpp`

Comment: `g++ patricia-merkle-trie.cpp dp.cpp -o ...`

Comment: You forgot to link `db.o`. so of course the linker cannot find anything in it.

Comment: Sometimes it's the obvious thing (actually most of the time it's the obvious thing).